# Decrypting Two Strings That Have Been Combined After Encryption?

Tags: c#, encryption

I find myself needing to decrypt a string that is actually two strings that have been encrypted separately and then joined as a single string.

For Instance,

When I encrypt.. 'foo123' it will return something like this:

> DPm5OtCV+6JSyWo1JIo4UQ==

Now I have another string I need to encrypt.. say.. 'bar321'

Let's say this returns something like:

> Z+0IEvXdmz8q/6XRU8/gsQ==

No problem, we can convert back and forth between them individually.

However, let's say I need to decrypt them as a single string:

> DPm5OtCV+6JSyWo1JIo4UQ==Z+0IEvXdmz8q/6XRU8/gsQ==

When I attempt this, it throws an exception:

> System.FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it
>   contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or
>   an illegal character among the padding characters.    at
>   System.Convert.FromBase64_ComputeResultLength(Char* inputPtr, Int32
>   inputLength)    at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr,
>   Int32 inputLength)    at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
>   at AesModule.DecryptStringToString(String input) in

Code Used:

```
internal void InitializeProviderWithKey(string key, string iv)
{
    try
    {
        m_Aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

        m_Aes.BlockSize = 128;
        m_Aes.KeySize = 256;
        m_Aes.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(iv);
        m_Aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
        m_Aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        m_Aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    }

    catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
}

internal string EncryptStringToString(string input)
{
    try
    {
        ICryptoTransform transform = m_Aes.CreateEncryptor();

        return Convert.ToBase64String
            (transform.TransformFinalBlock(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input), 0, input.Length));
    }

    catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); return null; }
}

internal string DecryptStringToString(string input)
{
    try
    {
        ICryptoTransform transform = m_Aes.CreateDecryptor();

        byte[] encoded = Convert.FromBase64String(input);

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString
            (transform.TransformFinalBlock(encoded, 0, encoded.Length));
    }

    catch(Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); return null; }
}
```

Is this possible?

Is there maybe another cipher/padding combination that supports this?

Is it an issue with my code?

*Note: I have tried replacing Encoding.Ascii.GetBytes/GetString with Convert.ToBase64 methods.

Comment: You decrypt two strings as one that were encrypted separately.  The length is part of the encrypt/decrypt method.

Comment: Base64 doesn't line up with the usual 8-bit boundaries of bytes. You can't just concat two base64 strings and decode them in one go. As soon as you have padding chars (`=`) this will not work.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Judging by the rest of you code you should really read up on encodings, encryption and cypher modes. You mix a lot of things as if they interchangeable.

Comment: Simply split on `===`, `==` or `=` in that order of precedence. Be sure to maintain the padding. If there is no padding you won't know where the strings were concatenated so, you won't be able to decrypt the bytes that you have decoded.

Comment: One more thing: Since you are using CBC, you can't even decrypt them in one go even if the base64 would line up.

Comment: So why am I getting down votes for a question that I could not find a duplicate of? I know the stack overflow trolls would have been quick to point out if there was one. So are we not allowed to ask questions to confirm something?

Comment: That's a valid question so don't worry that you were for some reason downvoted (for no reason I'd say). That happens, but rarely.

Comment: @Evk agreed, you could always ask again

Comment: Downvotes are not only given for duplicates. The tooltip of the downvote button says *"This question does not show any research effort"*. To me it is obvious that you have not bothered finding out why your code fails. You have made mistakes at every single step of your encryption/decryption - so you obviously didn't research what you were doing, you simply pasted you non-working code here so others can figure it out for you.

Comment: @Evk Hehe, there's a reason I call them trolls.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer both encrypt and decrypt functions posted in question will work just fine for regular string encryption\decryption. But will not for concatenated encrypted string (obviously) - that's a problem stated in question.

Comment: Both @Manfred and Evk are giving good advice, it is the down votes without comments that should be more annoying. Either way, the onus is on the asker to improve.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer The code works. Try it out. :) I'm sorry you're so angry but please don't tell how much effort I've put forth. The code fails only when trying to decrypt two separately encrypted strings. It's obviously an issue of padding.. As the exception says. So before telling me I put no effort into my question maybe you should put the effort into testing it before claiming it doesn't work.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer but you are saying that OP copied code from himself, since you are pointing to his other question.

Comment: @Eidenai It's not just an *"issue of padding"*. As I've stated before you are using the wrong cipher mode if you want to concat multiple strings. If you read my comments again (not just the parts that apparently offend you), you'll see there is a lot more information in there.

Comment: @EvK Woops, scratch that, my bad.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer The exception.. says.. The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. Not to mention I specifically asked if there was another cipher or padding mode I could use.. Have a good day man, I hope it gets better.

Comment: @Eidenai To summarize, since you apparently don't want to re-read my comments: You are using the wrong cipher mode (read how CBC works), your base64 encoding doesn't line up (you will have to come up with your own way of making sure that doesn't happen), and you can't have padding chars (base64 padding, not AES padding!) within your string.

Comment: If you absolutely cannot control how this base64 string is concatenated (so that you cannot add separator) - you can achieve what you want with ECB mode, but this mode is considered very insecure and is not recommended to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A suggestion:

Commas [cannot occur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16681037/1132334) in a valid base64 string.
Use a comma to join the individual parts of your encrypted string. On decryption, split it up again and feed the parts to the decryption function one by one.

Comment: Thanks man, I didn't know that about the commas. Probably a better option than using '==' like I was going to do - honestly I was just trying to avoid another split operation. I'd +1 if I could :)